# VBA HTML scrape calendar elements

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I want to scrape the ECB's weekly schedule for upcoming events through VBA. However, I only want to scrape information about speeches (not data releases etc.) on given dates. To be specific, I have a table in excel with "Date", "TimeStamp", "BoardMember" and "Event" as column headers that I want to populate.

So far, I'm able to match the dates in HTML (dt) with the date in my array of dates in excel through an "if"-statement, but I cannot figure out how to return the innerTexts of the given classes ("boardMember", "time" and "event") in the description (dd) that follows right after the specific date.
This only goes for the events that have a class = "boardMember" (event 2 in the attached HTML code)

So can I somehow set *eventq* in the following VBA code to the dd class and only continue if it contains a class named "boardMember"?

**VBA code**

```
Sub ImportECBSpeaker()

'to refer to the running copy of Internet Explorer
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
'to refer to the HTML document returned
Dim html As HTMLDocument
'open Internet Explorer in memory, and go to website
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True ' set to False when done
ie.navigate "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/calendars/weekly/html/index.en.html"
'Wait until IE is done loading page
Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to ECB Calendar ..."

DoEvents

Loop

'show text of HTML document returned
Set html = ie.document
'close down IE and reset status bar
Set ie = Nothing

Application.StatusBar = ""

'clear old data out and put titles in
Cells.Clear

'put heading across the top of row 3
Range("A2").Value = "Date"
Range("B2").Value = "Time"
Range("C2").Value = "Board Member"
Range("D2").Value = "Event"

'Dates I want to lookup
Dim datesarray(1 To 5), n As Integer, i As Integer
For n = 1 To 5
    datesarray(n) = Format((Date + (1 - Application.Weekday(Date, 2) + n - 1)), "dddd, d mmm yyyy")
Next n

Dim Content As IHTMLElement
Dim dates As IHTMLElementCollection, events As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim dateq As IHTMLElement, eventq As IHTMLElement

Set Content = html.getElementById("ecb-content-col")
Set dates = Content.getElementsByTagName("dt")
Set events = Content.getElementsByTagName("dd")

Dim Rownumber As Integer, dateqString As String
Rownumber = 3

For i = 1 To 5
    For Each dateq In dates
    'For Each eventq In events
        dateqString = dateq.innerText
        
            If dateqString = datesarray(i) Then
                
                'Set eventq = THE dd below the date matched
                
                'If eventq.className = "boardMember" Then
                    Cells(Rownumber, 1).Value = dateqString
                    Cells(Rownumber, 2).Value = eventq.getElementByClassName("time").innerText 'Timestamp
                    Cells(Rownumber, 3).Value = eventq.getElementByClassName("boardMember").innerText 'board member
                    Cells(Rownumber, 4).Value = eventq.getElementByClassName("event").innerText 'event
                    Rownumber = Rownumber + 1
                'Else
                'End If
            Else
            End If
    Next dateq
Next i

End Sub
```

**HTML Example of 2 events with event specific details**

```
<div id="ecb-content-col" >
                    <main>
                        <h1>Weekly schedule of public speaking engagements and other activities</h1>
<h3>Friday, 17 July 2020 - Sunday, 26 July 2020</h3>
<dl class="ecb-basicList">
<dt >Monday, 20 Jul 2020</dt>
<dd>
<span class="event"><span class="label">Event:</span>Euro area monthly balance of payments (Dataset: BP6)</span>
<span class="time"><span class="label">Time:</span>10:00 CET</span>
<span class="infoWeb"><span class="label">Info website:</span><a class="arrow" href="https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pr/stats/bop/html/index.en.html" target="_self">https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pr/stats/bop/html/index.en.html</a></span>
<span class="lastModified">Last modified: 20 July 2020, 11:05 CET</span>
</dd>
<dt >Monday, 20 Jul 2020</dt>
<dd>
<span class="boardMember"><span class="label">Board member:</span>Luis de Guindos</span>
<span class="event"><span class="label">Event:</span>Participation by Mr de Guindos in the panel &quot;La respuesta europea frente a la crisis&quot; organised by Universidad Complutense de Madrid as part of the Cursos de verano de El Escorial</span>
<span class="time"><span class="label">Time:</span>10:00 CET</span>
<span class="venue"><span class="label">Venue:</span>Real Colegio Universitario Mar&iacute;a Cristina. Paseo de los Alamillos, 2, 28200 San Lorenzo de El Escorial, Madrid, Spain</span>
<span class="contact"><span class="label">Contact:</span>Esther Tejedor - ECB Global Media Relations - Tel: +49 69 1344 95596 - Mob: +49 172 5171280</span>
<span class="email"><span class="label">E-mail:</span><a class="mail" href="mailto:esther.tejedor@ecb.europa.eu">esther.tejedor@ecb.europa.eu</a></span>
<span class="infoWeb"><span class="label">Info website:</span><a class="external" href="www.pp.es" target="_blank">www.pp.es</a></span>
<span class="text"><span class="label">Text:</span>No text will be made available.</span>
<span class="notes"><span class="label">Notes:</span>The event will be streamed in Spanish via the above-mentioned link.</span>
<span class="lastModified">Last modified: 20 July 2020, 11:05 CET</span>
</dd>
</dl>
<script type="text/javascript">
                                var currentContentsUrl = "/press/calendars/weekly/html/index_content.en.html";
                            </script>


                    </main>
                        
                </div>
```